# azure pipeline pull dependency projects

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, pipeline

I have a project which depends on 2-3 other projects, is there a way to pull them together with the master project?

When the build process starts projects will be on the file system and the master project can locate the other dependency projects?

Comment: Have you looked at [multi-repo checkout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/multi-repo-checkout?view=azure-devops) ?

Comment: @KehindeLadipo i didn't but will give a try

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Kehinde's said in comment, what you want could be achieved by the feature [Multi-repo checkout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/multi-repo-checkout?view=azure-devops).

**Note**:

**Multi-repo checkout** is the feature which **only** supported `YAML`. Because what the design logic is Checkouts from multiple repos in combination with YAML builds enable focusing the source level dependency management to one structured descriptor file in Git (the YAML biuld definition) for **good visibility**.

But for pipeline that configured by `classic UI`, you had to add those other repositories/projects as `submodules`, or as manual scripts to run `git checkout` in pipeline.

---

*For personal, I strongly suggest you use YAML to achieve what you want.*

**Simple sample YAML definition:**

```
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: tools
    name: Tools
    type: git

steps:
- checkout: self
- checkout: tools
- script: dir $(Build.SourcesDirectory)
```

*Here, image I have a repository called "MyCode" with a YAML pipeline, plus a second repository called "Tools".*

In above third `step`(*dir $(Build.SourcesDirectory)*), it will show you two directories, "**MyCode**" and "**Tools**", in the sources directory.

Hope this helps.

---

For Bitbucket:

```
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: MyBitBucketRepo
    type: bitbucket
    endpoint: MyBitBucketServiceConnection
    name: {BitBucketOrg}/{BitBucketRepo}

trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:
- checkout: self
- checkout: MyBitBucketRepo
- script: dir $(Build.SourcesDirectory)
```

Comment: Should all projects be created as pipeline so i can add them as dependency or one pipeline is enough but in yaml ill configure from where to pull other projects?

Comment: one more note that my projects are in bitbucket, so i need to pull from bitbucket the projects.

Comment: @EmrahMehmedov, okay, one important things is you are using Bitbucket cloud?Or server? In addition, not too understand what you very concerned, could you express more?

Comment: Bitbucket cloud, instead pulling from repositories hosted on azure can i pull from bitbucket?

Comment: @EmrahMehmedov, Yes! you can. We does not support pull repos from Bitbucket server, this is why I confirm with you just now. To fetch repos from bitbucket cloud, you need firstly create service connection with bitbucket cloud. Then follow the YAML scripts (update in my answer) to configure your YAML.